# Ansible Galaxy roles incorrect path

Tags: linux, ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-galaxy

When i install anything via ansible-galaxy like

```
ansible-galaxy install 1nfinitum.php
```

it is saved in

```
/root/.ansible/roles/1nfinitum.php
```

but the default path like mentioned in [Galaxy](https://galaxy.ansible.com/docs/using/installing.html) is

```
 /etc/ansible/roles
```

My ansible.cfg

```
 #inventory      = /etc/ansible/hosts
 #library        = /usr/share/my_modules/
 #module_utils   = /usr/share/my_module_utils/
 #remote_tmp     = ~/.ansible/tmp
 #local_tmp      = ~/.ansible/tmp
```

why roles are not getting stored in default path what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q: *"Why roles are not getting stored in default path what am I doing wrong ?"*

A: Find out how the configuration was changed. Run the command

```
shell> ansible-config dump --only-changed
```

and search `DEFAULT_ROLES_PATH`. For example

```
DEFAULT_ROLES_PATH(/home/admin/.ansible.cfg) = ['/home/admin/.ansible/roles']
```

You'll find out who and how changed the default configuration.

Comment: Thank you, i just uncommented # and it seems to work fine. thanks again

        roles_path    = /etc/ansible/roles